# Upload multiple file with vue js and axios

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

**I am trying to upload multiple images using vuejs and axios but on server side i am getting empty object.** I added multipart/form-data in header but still empty object.

```js
submitFiles() {
    /*
      Initialize the form data
    */
    let formData = new FormData();

    /*
      Iteate over any file sent over appending the files
      to the form data.
    */
    for( var i = 0; i < this.files.length; i++ ){
      let file = this.files[i];
      console.log(file);
      formData.append('files[' + i + ']', file);
    }

    /*`enter code here`
      Make the request to the POST /file-drag-drop URL
    */
    axios.post( '/fileupload',
      formData,
      {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        },
      }
    ).then(function(){
    })
    .catch(function(){
    });
  },
```

**HTML:**

```html
<form method="post" action="#" id="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group files text-center" ref="fileform">
        <input type="file"  multiple="multiple">
        <span id='val'></span>
        <a class="btn"  @click="submitFiles()" id='button'>Upload Photo</a>
        <h6>DRAG & DROP FILE HERE</h6>
    </div>
```

My Server side code:

```php
class FileSettingsController extends Controller
{
    public function upload(Request $request){
        return $request->all();
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
{files: [{}]}
files: [{}]
0: {}
```

Console.log() result:
`File(2838972) {name: "540340.jpg", lastModified: 1525262356769, lastModifiedDate: Wed May 02 2018 17:29:16 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 2838972, …}`

Comment: did you figured it out? im having the same problem

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You forgot to use `$refs`. Add `ref` to your input:

```html
<input type="file" ref="file" multiple="multiple">
```

Next, access your files like this:

```js
submitFiles() {

    const formData = new FormData();

    for (var i = 0; i < this.$refs.file.files.length; i++ ){
        let file = this.$refs.file.files[i];
        formData.append('files[' + i + ']', file);
    }

    axios.post('/fileupload', formData, {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        },
      }
    ).then(function(){
    })
    .catch(function(){
    });
},
```

This should be works.

Comment: What about `dd($request->file('files'))` in your controller? What output have you got?

Comment: `array:1 [
  0 => UploadedFile {#756
    -test: false
    -originalName: "540340.jpg"
    -mimeType: "image/jpeg"
    -error: 0
    #hashName: null
    path: "C:\xampp\tmp"
    filename: "php44C8.tmp"
    basename: "php44C8.tmp"
    pathname: "C:\xampp\tmp\php44C8.tmp"
    extension: "tmp"
    realPath: "C:\xampp\tmp\php44C8.tmp"
    aTime: 2019-02-04 16:32:27
    mTime: 2019-02-04 16:32:27
    type: "file"
    writable: true
    readable: true
    executable: false
    file: true
    dir: false
    link: false
    linkTarget: "C:\xampp\tmp\php44C8.tmp"
  }
]`

Comment: So you got it, now you need to store them.

Comment: if there are fields that contain strings how do we combine them?

Comment: @AhmadBudairi, you have to append data with the string value, ie. `formData.append('title', this.form.title);`

Answer (score 4):

If anyone wondering, "How can I send also data with it", there you go:

```
formData.append('name[' + this.name + ']', name);
formData.getAll('files', 'name');
```

Answer (score 2):

For Composition API this should work:

```
const files = ref([])

function save() {
  let formData = new FormData()
  for (let file of files.value) {
    formData.append('files', file)
  }
  axios.post('/upload', formData, {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
    },
  })
  .then((response) => {
  })
}
```

Comment: For Laravel, at least, it seems I can't just send multiple "files" and I have to manually add an array notation, i.e. `files[0] ... files[3]` while using append.